# How to add an animation delay to every child of a css class

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I want to make a cascading style, card slide up animation.

I already made the slide up part, and it's working. The problem is that all the cards slide up at the same time.

I would like to know how to add a delay to each one. Since the number of cards can change from time to time, I can't use css `:nth-child(n)` selector to make it happen.

Heres the HTML

```
<div class='entry animated slideInEntry'>

    <div>
        <span>$submitter</span>
        <span>$amount</span>
    </div>

    <div>$ratingIcon</div>

</div>
```

And this is the CSS animation

```
/* Entry Card Animation -Entry Card Animation -Entry Card Animation -Entry Card Animation -Entry Card Animation */

.slideInEntry{
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInEntry;
          animation-name: slideInEntry;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
          animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideInEntry{

  0%{
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 500px;
  }

  50%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(500px);
            transform: translateY(500px);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  100%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }

}

@keyframes slideInEntry{
  0%{
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 500px;
  }

  50%{
     -webkit-transform: translateY(500px);
            transform: translateY(500px);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  100%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this JQuery code:

```
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

  var intv = setInterval(function() {
    $("#span" + count).show();
    $("#span" + count).addClass("entry animated slideInEntry");
    if (count > $("span").length) {
      clearInterval(intv);
      return;
    } else {
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sampada07/vffxd80w/2/

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't work for me. Since I want to animate just the container  not the spans. I tweaked it but I didn't work.